# use of AWK for obtaining non negative value

Tags: awk

I am trying to make my second column as non negative as some of the values are positive and some negative, so trying AWK function.

I have six columns in my bed file I am using the following command

```
awk -F"\t"  '{print $1"\t"$2<0?$2*-1:$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' CTCF_first_coordinates > CTCF_first_coordinates_new
```

My problem is when I run this, then my first column is not printed and the values are not converted to non negative. However if i don't print my first column the code works.

Can anybody suggest how can I improve my code to get the proper output?

Below is the input bed file which is tab delimited and second column contain negative values together with positive values

```
chr18 576980 586980 CETN1 CLUL1 M1 
chr18 -8280 1720 NA USP14 M1
```

and the output i need is below where I want the negative value to be positive and rest everything remains same

```
chr18 576980 586980 CETN1 CLUL1 M1 
chr18 8280 1720 NA USP14 M1
```

In addition to the above problem I have some more issue where the output file as shown above the first coordinate is larger than the second coordinate. Is there any method to interchange the selected values of the two columns in the file i.e column 2 and 3. I have 192 such instances in the whole file. So my output should be something like

chr18 576980 586980 CETN1 CLUL1 M1 
chr18 1720   8280  NA USP14 M1

Comment: please show some input file together with the desired output

Comment: The example below is the input file

chr17   78614606        78624606        B3GNTL1 METRNL  M1
chr17   78364327        78374327        FN3K    ZNF750  M1
chr17   78618175        78628175        B3GNTL1 METRNL  M1
chr18   576980  586980  CETN1   CLUL1   M1
chr18   -8280   1720    NA      USP14   M1

Comment: Please [edit] your question with such information. It is difficult to track files and code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the sign if it is negative:

```
$ awk '$2<0 {$2=-$2}1' file
chr18 576980 586980 CETN1 CLUL1 M1 
chr18 8280 1720 NA USP14 M1
```

The `1` at the end of the command is a way to set something to `True` in `awk`, so that it performs its default behaviour: print the current line.

Comment: @PrasoonAgarwal I guess it was a matter of parentheses, since `'{print $1"\t"($2<0?$2*-1:$2)"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}'` works. Note also that you can set the output field separator like `-v OFS="\t"` so that you don't have to hardcode it in the `print` expression.